# Help with WP Business Directory Manager Plugin?

Tags: plugins, php, functions

I'm using the WP Business Directory Manager plugin and I'm having some problems. The developer hasn't been supporting the plugin lately, so here I am.

- I need to change the field order. Currently the option is there, but it doesn't work.
- I need to target the field for CSS purposes, with custom classes/ids
- And I need to be able to query the post from certain categories from its directory. I would want to post different list on throughout the site and Im not sure how to do that.

The plugin is very useful, I just need some help with these issues...PLEASE.

Thanks for any help that can be provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the field order, you can delete all the fields and then add them again in the order of your choosing. Sucks to have to do it that way, but whatever. It's a free program.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Since then I've been using the CouponPress theme. Its not necessarily a business directory, but theres are plugins to add that capability.